# How do I invert my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that i want to invert how do i do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This really depends on whether you mean invert or reverse?

If you want to invert your keys with the values then take a look at `array_flip` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

```
<?php 

$values = array("Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"); 
print_r($values); 

$values = array_flip($values); 
print_r($values); 
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item 1
    [1] => Item 2
    [2] => Item 3
)
Array
(
    [Item 1] => 0
    [Item 2] => 1
    [Item 3] => 2
)
?>
```

if you want to reverse your array then use `array_reverse` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

```
<?php
$values = array("Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"); 
print_r($values); 

$values = array_reverse($values);
print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item 1
    [1] => Item 2
    [2] => Item 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => Item 3
    [1] => Item 2
    [2] => Item 1
)
?>
```

You may also want to reverse the array but key the values assigned to their keys in that case you will want `$values = array_reverse($values, true);`

Comment: `array_flip` pairs great with `fgetcsv` for when column headers may not be in an expected order. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_reverse`](http://co.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$array_inverted = array_reverse($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option you my want to consider as well is simply read the array from bottom to top instead of from top to bottom if the situation allows for it.